# Refactoring a if statement having multiple 'and' and 'or' statements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refactoring

What is best way to refactor or make more readable this chunk of code in ruby ?

```
 def check(message_type)
    if (message_type == 'reminder' and self.copy_reminder == true) or
            (message_type == 'rrm' and self.is_rrm == true and self.copy_rrm == true) or
            (message_type == 'alert' and self.is_rrm == true and self.copy_alert == true) or
            (message_type == 'reply' and self.is_rrm == true and self.copy_user_response == true)
          call_some_method
end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: For one thing: don't use `and` and `or`

Comment: Looks pretty readable to me.

Comment: Also, get rid of all `self` - they're obsolete.

Comment: ... and of the `== true` parts (except if you *really* care that `is_rrm` returns the actual `true` object)

Comment: `def check(message_type)
  case message_type
  when "reminder" return unless copy_reminder == true
  when "rrm" return unless is_rrm == true and copy_rrm == true
  when "alert" return unless is_rrm == true and copy_alert == true
  when "reply" return unless is_rrm == true and copy_user_response == true
  else return
  call_some_method
end`

Comment: Or if you change other parts of the code to avoid truthy values other than `true`, then `def check(message_type)
  case message_type
  when "reminder" return unless copy_reminder
  when "rrm" return unless is_rrm and copy_rrm
  when "alert" return unless is_rrm and copy_alert
  when "reply" return unless is_rrm and copy_user_response
  else return
  call_some_method
end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `and` or `or` in boolean condition, use `&&` and `||`. `and` and `or` are for control flow. Do not use `self.` when reading an attribute, you just do not need it. Do not check booleans like this `some_thing == true`, `some_thing` is *trueish* enough.

And I prefer to move complex conditions into private methods. That keeps the method that actual does something more readable.

```
  def check(message_type)
    call_some_method if valid_message_type?(message_type)
  end

private

  def valid_message_type?(message_type)
    case message_type
    when 'reminder' then copy_reminder
    when 'rrm'      then is_rrm && copy_rrm
    when 'alert'    then is_rrm && copy_alert
    when 'reply'    then is_rrm && copy_user_response
    end
  end
```